# How to read for data from CDC device connected to Android using usb-serial-for-android?

Tags: android, usbserial, adafruit

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android) to send and receive data from a Feather 32u4 device. The Feather sends some canned data when the port is opened, and then echos back what is sent to it.

I'm having issues understanding how the `read` and `write` methods work in the library. I'm pretty sure I'm using `write` correctly, but I don't know about `read`. The returned length when `read` is used is always 0, and I am using the correct baudrate. I'm just not totally sure *how* it should be used. I'm still trying to figure out the event driven option also.

```
private void DoTheThing () {

      String textMessage = "";

      UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);



      // Find available drivers for Feather board.
      ProbeTable customTable = new ProbeTable();
      customTable.addProduct(0x239a, 0x800c, CdcAcmSerialDriver.class);
      UsbSerialProber prober = new UsbSerialProber(customTable);
      List<UsbSerialDriver> drivers = prober.findAllDrivers(manager);
      if (drivers.isEmpty()) {
         textMessage += "Could not find any drivers.\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
         return;
      }

      textMessage += "Driver found\n";
      m_textView.setText(textMessage);

      UsbDeviceConnection connection = null;
      UsbSerialDriver driver = drivers.get(0);
      PendingIntent usbPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB), 0);
      manager.requestPermission(driver.getDevice(), usbPermissionIntent);
      try {
         connection = manager.openDevice(driver.getDevice());
      } catch (Exception e) {
         textMessage += e + "\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
      }
      if (connection == null) {
         // add UsbManager.requestPermission(driver.getDevice(), ..) handling here
         textMessage += "Could not open device.\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
         return;
      }

      textMessage += "Device opened\n";
      m_textView.setText(textMessage);

      UsbSerialPort port = driver.getPorts().get(0);
      // Most devices have just one port (port 0)
      try {
         port.open(connection);
         port.setParameters(115200, 8, UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         textMessage += e + "\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
         return;
      }

      textMessage += "Connection established\n";
      m_textView.setText(textMessage);

      // Get received data on connection.
      int length = -2;
      byte[] receivedData = new byte[64];
      try {
         length = port.read(receivedData, 2000);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         textMessage += "Oops: " + e + "\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
      }

      String data = new String(receivedData);
      textMessage += "Data recieved: " + length + " " + data + "\n";
      m_textView.setText(textMessage);


      // Send canned data.
      length = -2;
      try {
         length = port.write("a".getBytes(), 2000);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         textMessage += "Oops: " + e + "\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
      }

      textMessage += "Data sent " + length + "\n";
      m_textView.setText(textMessage);

      // Get received data.
      length = -2;
      receivedData = new byte[64];
      try {
         length = port.read(receivedData, 2000);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         textMessage += "Oops: " + e + "\n";
         m_textView.setText(textMessage);
      }

      data = new String(receivedData);
      textMessage += "Data recieved: " + length + " " + data;
      m_textView.setText(textMessage);

   }
```

[image]

<s>EDIT</s>

Getting a hard crash when I set the DTR flag to true on my port.

```
  m_port = driver.getPorts().get(0);

  // Most devices have just one port (port 0)
  try {
     m_port.setDTR(true);   //  <-- hard crash
     m_port.open(connection);
     m_port.setParameters(115200, 8, UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     m_textMessage += e + "\n";
     m_textView.setText(m_textMessage);
     return;
  }
```

Could `m_port` still be uninitialized when it gets to that point?

Derp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

length is 0 when nothing is received within the 2000 msec timeout.

For CDC devices like the 32u4 you typically have to set DTR line as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android/wiki/Troubleshooting#i-am-using-an-arduino-uno-sparkfun-pro-micro-or-other-arduino-and-if-serial-doesnt-work)

Comment: I'm getting a hard crash when I set that flag. See OP edit.

Comment: Derp. `setDTR` need to be after the port is opened.